# Sudo breaks node module resolution for relative path

Tags: node.js, sudo

I have a node project with structure like

```
/mymodule
--/bin
 --/myscript
--/package.json
.
.
.
```

bin/myscript looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const mymodule = require('..').mymodule;
```

When I launch the script as a normal user everything works fine. When I try to run the script with sudo the module resolution breaks with the error

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mymodule/bin/myscript)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Why does the module resolution fail when running with sudo?

Comment: What command are you executing on the shell to run the script? if you used home relative path there (using ~), that could cause issues.

Comment: From the project dir I'm running bin/myscript. No home path involved in launching.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was not with module loading, but rather the fact that npm by default demotes its own privileges when running pre/post install scripts. As a result the module was actually missing because the post install script didn't create the build directory. I missed a warning in the spew when installing the project:

```
npm WARN lifecycle <my module>@<my version>~postinstall: cannot run in wd
```

Not running with sudo wasn't an option so I was able to resolve this by using the `--unsafe-perm` flag with npm:

```
$ npm install --unsafe-perm
```